# Books on Mathematical Logic?

Tags: logic, reference-request, soft-question

Does anybody have any recommendations for books in Mathematical logic; Set theory, Category theory, Theory of computation...?

Comment: Why do you use the term "mathematical logic"? Is there a difference between "logic" and "mathematical logic"?

Comment: If you are newbie in Mathematical logic I would recommend Introduction to mathematical logic by Mendelson.

Comment: Peter Smith maintains a comprehensive guide http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/

Comment: @James Arathoon: I don't know if this is the OP's reason, but "mathematical logic" is often used to differentiate from things like symbolic logic, formal logic, and natural (language) logic that are taught in philosophy (and sometimes other) departments, and which have much larger enrollments (at least in the U.S.) than courses in mathematical logic.

Answer (score 1):

During my BSc I used these texts:

1. Introduction to set theory, K. Hrbacek and T. Jech
2. Conceptual Mathematics: A First Introduction to Categories by  Stephen H. Schanuel
3. The Categorial Analysis of Logic by Robert Goldblatt